# Is there a neutral word for the sense that something is ever-present and close by?

Tags: single-word-requests

Like 'omnipresent' but not currently seen, heard etc. rather knowing the chance of the presence of something/someone could be near.

Examples---

I won't go swimming because of the ____ of a dangerous animal.

I feel safe because of the ____ of the police.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not sure how to clarify this any further. What is confusing about it?

Comment: Show how you would use this word. Provide a sentence where you insert a blank for the word you’re looking for.

Comment: Not a single word, but “I won’t go swimming *for fear of* dangerous animals.  I won’t commit a crime for fear of the police.”

Comment: I was hoping for a neutral word. I couldn't think of an example sentence.

Comment: Why isn't omnipresent sufficient? Deities are often characterized as omnipresent, despite never being seen or heard. Something can be omnipresent and yet never actually encountered.

Comment: There are a number of words that can in principle replace your blanks (and that *in principle* have the required meaning), such as ***omnipresence, universality, pervasiveness, pervasion, all-presence, ubiquitousness,...*** But *in practice* a native Anglophone probably wouldn't try to use that construction in the first place. On the other hand, *I won't go swimming because of **all the** dangerous animals* and *I won't commit this crime because **the police are everywhere*** are both perfectly natural ways of saying something like that.

Comment: Note that it doesn't make sense to ask for a "neutral" term when both the example contexts where you want to use the term involve not doing something (that you might otherwise have wanted to do) ***because the ubiquitous presence of [dangerous animals, police] deters you***.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie perhaps you're right. I attribute omnipresent to specifically the divine, but it can be used in a much more general way than that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers edited so both are not examples of deterrence

Comment: Apart from the title, **proximity** works with both examples.

Comment: Why do you need a single word?  Sometimes two or even three words can be just as strong as one, or even stronger.

Comment: And why the same word in both examples, which are opposite in the sense of security and danger?

Comment: @WeatherVane - Except that in when committing crimes the police don’t provide security…

Comment: @Jim I guess you have reversed the sense of OP's intention.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Agh!  OP’s original second example was “If I commit a crime …” I didn’t notice that he’d changed it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a word I'd use in everyday conversation (except tongue-in-cheek) as it falutes too highly, but **omnipresence** has the desired meaning here, at least according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/omnipresence):

> *omnipresence*: the quality or state of being omnipresent: ubiquity

> [*omnipresent*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/omnipresent) : present in all places at all times

Other dictionaries tend to be less explicit about the 'at all times' requirement. The M-W definition warrants an answer, I feel, though this word  has been mentioned in comments [@FumbleFingers] and fits the title question but not the examples (far too formal).

Comment: I can easily convince myself that with OP's examples, a native speaker might say *...because of the **ever-present dangerous animals*** or *...because the **police are everywhere***. But I can't imagine a native speaker using ***omnipresent*** in either context, unless the speaker was being deliberately quirky / facetious. As you say, the exact word that fits the *meaning* is far too formal for the *context*.

Comment: Your answers are what OP should use. I add this answer merely to show that 'omnipresent'  at least overlaps with 'eternal', which I'd never really considered before. But of course one's into philosophy now.